# How can I create a task in vscode (tasks.json) that runs a .ps1 script from any document?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I write text files in markdown format, in Visual Studio Code. I have a powershell script (.ps1) that I use to convert a markdown file (.md) to a pdf file. I would like to execute the .ps1 by creating a task.

**I have tried to create a task**:

Ctrl+Shift+P -->
Tasks: configure default build task>open tasks.json file>Others

This is what tasks.json looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [ 
        { 
            "name": "RUN md to pdf", 
            "type": "PowerShell", 
            "program": "C:/Users/tomas/OneDrive/Dokument/_markdown/kandidat/script/_RUN.ps1"
        } 
    ] 
}
```

Where _RUN.ps1 is the script I want to execute. Note one thing: the script says "version": "0.2.0". But when I look around for a solution, it the version is "**2**.0". I have the latest vscode installed (1.63.2), on windows 11.

**What I expected to happen:** I would have a task called "RUN md to pdf" that I could execute by pressing ctrl+shift+B.

But when I press ctrl+shift+B I just get "No build task to run found..."

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you configuring the tasks.json instead of the keybindings.json?

Comment: Well, my problem was that my tasks.json script was just coded wrong. I found the solution and added it as an answer. But the next step is to add the task as a hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So I found a solution. Mytasks.json no looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
     "tasks": [ 
        {               
            "type": "shell", 
            "label": "Create PDF", 
            "detail": "Use _RUN.ps1 to convert md to pdf with Pandoc",
            "command": "C:/Users/tomas/OneDrive/Dokument/_markdown/kandidat/script/_RUN.ps1"
        } 
    ] 
}
```

If I press ctrl+shift+B I get the option to choose my task (Create PDF) and the next time I press ctrl+shift+B  it will just execute my .ps1 file. Success!